# Is there any where I can upload two strings xml files to be translated?

Tags: android, language-translation

My app is going to be translated by several amateur translators for several languages. I can send them the xml file with all the strings that need to be translated. But, is there a cleaner way to have two files uploaded, the one in English and the one to be translated, to easily identify the strings that are still missing? Basically is like having the Translation Editor of Android Studio but online.
Maybe using google docs? How do you do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Google Docs**, but that's quite an outdated way to handle this.

**The major cons:**

- it would be cumbersome to update strings this way
- no easy way to make sure the new ones have new translations, not the old ones, etc.
- no good way to provide context, if needed (typically translators have questions). You can create a column with context and take any discussions into comments, but it can get messy

**A few pros:**

- it's fast to create (although slow to keep up-to-date)
- you cooperate online and have shared access

**Most developers use localization platforms**, which makes updating content and online cooperation much faster.

**Main pros:**

- it's easy to identify strings that are missing
- any number of translators can translate simultaneously
- track work that is done by each of translators
- you can add a review/proofreading step to the process to ensure the quality of translations
- leverage Machine Translations and then just have translators review them (saves lots of time)
- update content, as most platforms support agile workflow
- you can see who's the top translator (give some rewards, invite to other projects, etc.)
- integrations (with your Git tool, Android Studio, etc), so you can automate content updates, no manual copy-pasting

**Cons:**

- some of them are paid (still, if you're open source, you can expect a free plan)

Regarding the tools, I can suggest looking at [Crowdin](https://crowdin.com/) or [Poedit](https://poedit.net/).

There are many alternatives you can research, some are [listed on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_computer-assisted_translation_tools).

Answer (score 0):

At my work we had to translate english into Norwegian, we've done that by working with an python script that generated an ui from an csv file, after that the file could be exported in several formates as well. But your question indicates that you would like to deploy only on android, so this might be an overkill.

a simple python xml filter would fit your aproach and you could work as well with git as long as the lines stays in the same order.

if you need an quick example please comment, and ill edit this answer as soon as i get time.

Answer (score 0):

At one point I have also had the same question. I need the translation for my vernacular app, also I had the requirement to maintain such that I could easily compare the translation. Here I could suggest a few things that worked out for me.

1. First, take the string XML file and convert it in an Excel sheet, You may generate multiple excel sheet and having a copy, paste and merge all the translations into a single sheet.

Going forward it will be easy for you to maintain all the translation. Just share a single sheet which has a string key and multiple language column. So you could easily have a look at all language translations.

In the long run, it will be helpful to you.
Few links for the conversion of XML to excel -
[Convert string XML to Excel sheet](https://medium.com/@stanleylin_7768/android-convert-string-xml-to-csv-excel-70a4affd28bd)

Answer (score 0):

Using the below online tool works for me. **Free and Opensource** easy and best.

https://asrt.gluege.boerde.de/